# Lock excel reference to a single cell on another sheet / workbook even after moving the source

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want the formulas in Sheet02 to remain intact even after moving or deleting the cell data in Sheet01. The formulas in Sheet02 should always show what is in Sheet01 A1, A1, B1, B2, etc. When I move the cell A1 to C1, the formula in Sheet02 automatically turns to =Sheet01!C1 and I want it to remain at =Sheet01!A1.

Sheet01

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A2 | B2 |

Sheet02

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| =Sheet01!A1 | =Sheet01!B1 |
| =Sheet01!A2 | =Sheet01!B2 |

I have tried with VLOOKUP, but same result. Help apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is best solution but it works:

Write your formula as `=INDIRECT("Sheet01!A1")` it will not change whatever happens in Sheet01 but problem is you cant Copy/Fill this formula and each formula has to be writen separatly,

But if you want to return cells in same position but from Sheet01  you can adjust it like this: `=INDIRECT("Sheet01!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1))`

Hope it will help.

Comment: =INDIRECT("Sheet01!A1") works perfect! I didn't understand how to use the second formula though (returns an error). =INDIRECT("Sheet01!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1))

Comment: Well imagine that second formula is in cell Sheet02!B1  it will return value from Sheet01!B1. I just tought this way you can fill down this formula for as many rows as you need. It worked in my excel don't know where is problem. but i am glad firts solution worked :D

Comment: Okay, so =INDIRECT("Sheet01!"&ADDRESS(1;1;4;1)) returns Sheet01!A1. Is there any way to copy fill formula or do I have to write it separately? Both =INDIRECT("Sheet01!A1") and =INDIRECT("Sheet01!"&ADDRESS(1;1;4;1)) return the same and do work. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Using ROW() and COLUMN() will returm the number of the row or column your formula is in. Having =INDIRECT("Sheet01!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1)) in A1 will return the value of Sheet01!A1, having that formula in H39 will return the value in Sheet01!H39.